# Build a list of defined values into CTE

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

Is there any way to build a CTE for a list of hard coded values? For example, I have a list of known IDs (i.e. 101,102,105,200...), how would I be able to create a CTE with one column called ID but all the ID values are hard coded in the query? BTW, I need to run this query in Oracle. Thanks!

Answer (score 48):

EDIT: previously advised solution works only for MSSQL. Therefore I am adding an Oracle solution. I am keeping the original answer below.

I thought of one more solution (though the one provided by Justin Cave still seems a bit better) - using temporary tables.

Here is how it may look like

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp_ids
   (id INT)
   ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO ids (id) VALUES (101);
INSERT INTO ids (id) VALUES (102);
INSERT INTO ids (id) VALUES (103);
```

This should be a valid solution for Oracle database.

Original answer below

---

I have come across similar issue and here is my solution (this does not work on Oracle DB as mentioned in comments, only MSSQL though)

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            (1, 2, 3, ...),
            (2, 3, 4, ...)
        ) AS a (col1, col2, col3, ...)
    )
INSERT INTO ...
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This syntax is not valid in Oracle.

Comment: Therefore I am sorry for confusion and thank you for the information. Hopefully this will help someone else looking for the same in MSSQL.

Comment: Ok, I edited the previous answer and added what I think should be a valid solution for Oracle as well.

Comment: Note: VALUES is only available on SQL Server 2008 (v10) and later.

Comment: "Hopefully this will help someone else looking for the same in MSSQL" Yes, me!

Comment: FYI, the VALUES method shown here also works with IBM DB2 (or at least with what I'm using at the moment: AS/400 i5/OS v7.2).

Comment: This answer shows how to create and populate temp table, not CTE expression. OP is quite specific on this condition. I, personally, am leaning towards this answer - I actually prefer temp tables in that usage, but this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks @Zax - this worked perfectly for me. I am using SQL Server and did not want to create 2 tables for loading a cross join data into the application. This solution makes the task for my use case so much easier. Thanks

Answer (score 22):

You could do something like

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 101 id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 102 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 105 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 200 FROM dual UNION ALL
  ...
)
```

Depending on what you are really trying to accomplish, though, you may want to declare a collection and use that (with or without a function that parses a comma-separated string)

```
CREATE TYPE num_tbl
    AS TABLE OF NUMBER;

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT column_value
    FROM TABLE( num_tbl( 101, 102, 105, 200 ))
)
```

Comment: Just to add that recent versions allow column aliases for subquery factoring clauses to be separately defined, potentially keeping the query clause a bit neater: WITH cte (id) as (SELECT 101 from dual ... http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702

Answer (score 1):

You can use collection types for this, either submitting them as a bound parameter or creating them within your query.

As Justin Cave suggested, you can create your own collection type, but `SYS` contains a few for basic types that are defined by default, such as `SYS.ODCIDATELIST` (for `DATE`), `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST` (for `NUMBER`/`NUMERIC`), `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST` (for `VARCHAR2` up to 4000 chars), among those that don't seem specifically made for internal use.

Since you're using integer IDs, the built-in numeric collection sould work just fine:

```
-- column_value and table() work similarily to UNNEST() in Postgres
SELECT column_value as selected_id FROM TABLE(
    SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(101, 102, 105, 200)
)
```

Depending on what your host language supports, you can also send the list as a parameter instead. In Python, for instance, using cx_Oracle directly:

```
import cx_Oracle

query = 'select column_value as selected_id FROM TABLE(:id_list)'

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('user', 'hunter2', '//192.0.2.5:1521/mydb')

OdciNumberList = conn.gettype("SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST")
id_list = OdciNumberList.newobject()

id_list.extend([101, 102, 105, 200])

cur = conn.cursor()
res = cur.execute(query, id_list=id_list )
res.fetchall() # [(101,), (102,), (105,), (200,)]
```

Then you just need to wrap it in a CTE.

Comment: This solution is also convenient for very large `WHERE ... IN` lists, as shown in recent cx_Oracle documentation. It's worth noting that `gettype()` is relatively "expensive" and takes a few round-trips, so retain `OdciNumberList` and don't repeatedly call 'gettype()` if you need to do this more than once in the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

Slight improvement to Justin Cave's popular answer:

```
WITH cte (num) AS 
(
  SELECT 101 UNION SELECT 102 UNION SELECT 105 UNION SELECT 200
)

select num from cte
```